# Does the <h1> tag get more SEO value if there is no usable keyword in the URL?

Tags: seo, url, heading

I'm looking at a site for which the domain name and URL do not impart any meaningful data to a search engine.  It does have:

- `<h1>` (eBook name)
- `<h2>` (author - cannot be changed)
- `<p>` (description)

Do the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements provide SEO value?  Those are the only elements in that page that really provide any relevant information to search engines.   I see other sites that use keywords in their URL.

In theory, can the `<h1>` element be compared to a domain name in terms of SEO value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keywords are not needed in the domain name for a page to rank for that keyword.   Even keywords in the URL path don't help much (see [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant/47348))

The page title (`<title>`) is the place where words give the most ranking weight.  Other usages on the page can also help.

It is important to note that overusing a keyword can actually *hurt* rankings.   Using a keyword once in the title, once in the h1, and once in the page body is enough.   Using the keyword more than that is unlikely to help rankings.   Using the keyword more than that in ways that make the text awkward to read can cause keyword stuffing penalties.

Comment: What if the <title> is exactly the same as <h1> ?

Comment: A title and h1 that are the same is very common and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, no. It is a numbers game. Simple math really. Keyword in link + keyword in URL + keyword in path + keyword in resource name + keyword in `<h1>` + keyword in content = ?? There is no adjusting the weight of a keyword in `<h1>` because keywords are not found in the URL or path. However, having said that, search engines will use the keywords they find. If there are no keywords in some elements, then the keywords found become more important for search matches. Not more weight. Just what is available.

I hope I got your question right.