# Are URLs containing a slug but no directory (slash) OK for SEO and rich snippets?

Tags: seo, url, rich-snippets

I have single URL style for multiple different content types:

- `/question-title-1`
- `/article-title-2`

The questions have rich snippets for nostar voting and the articles have star voted rich snippets.

I commonly see web sites with a similar URL structure but which uses a slash between the content type and the slug:

- `/questions/title-1`
- `/articles/title-1`

My html page style is nearly identical between my content types.  Could I have problem with Google that my the same URL style has different HTML content types?   It it possible that Google might see this as an error?

Is it there any webpage who has same structure like me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to have no slash or directory in your URL separating your content type indicator from your title slug.   Google doesn't try to decipher URLs to figure out which ones look similar to others.    Google pays attention to which pages link to each other far more.   Your URL structure doesn't matter much for SEO these days.  Its best if you put some words in it to let users know what to expect ([more info](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant)), but worrying about slashes vs dashes isn't going to make any difference whatsoever.

As far as other sites go, almost half of all sites on the internet are built with WordPress.   [WordPress has a URL structure setting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) that has just the slug without any content type at all.   They call it the "post name" URL setting.  That is a very popular setting among WordPress sites.  Many sites use it and do just fine with SEO and rich snippets.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue but you can use your chance of using the right targeted keywords in URLs, titles, descriptions...it helps search engines and users to understand the structure of each page better and offer the most relevant content to users.

Maybe this article can help you:

https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls

Comment: Thanks i am going to try my chance lets see whats happen