# Is it worth using Cyrillic in URLs for better SEO

Tags: seo, url-encoding

My online shop currently uses Cyrillic directories since I am targeting Bulgaria, which has a Cyrillic alphabet. I did this in hopes of getting better ranks (it kind of worked I think).

It's also easier for file names when adding new categories and items in the shop.

1 year later I am redesigning this site since I am much more knowledgeable and want to make it better looking and better working.

But I am uncertain as to wheater I should keep the Cyrillic directories.
I can always use transcription for all the folders.

The Cyrillic URL only has one drawback that I know of - trying to copy and paste the URL results in this encoding

https://zadomaigradinata.bg/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-242.php

And by God this is hard to work with...
So I can imagine how frustrating it is for the users.

On the other hand thou, I don't want to let it go because of how neat and clean the URL looks and the possible SEO benefits.

**So is it worth keeping a Cyrillic directory for better SEO?**

Comment: You state that it’s bad for users, but only ask about SEO. Do you actually just want to know about the SEO aspect of it, no matter if it might be better for your users?

Comment: Where are you seeing the URL like that? Most browsers show the actual characters - for example I see `мебели-врати-легла/...` when I load your page.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I mentioned that it appears like that when you try to copy and paste the URL from the browser.

Comment: @unor I know its bad experience for users sometimes so I want to know if it actually that good for SEO ranking and is it worth keeping dispute that.

Comment: I'm don't think search engines put any weight on the URL these days.  All the benefits of using words are in the URL are for users.   See [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant)

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov: What I’m getting at was that I think it’s not bad for users (in the contrary, it might be *better* -- at least in general, I don’t know if Bulgaria might be an exception), but as you only ask about the SEO aspect, there is no room to discuss the usability aspect.

Answer (score 1):

it is not required, but it might help you rank better because it might be more exact match to the search phrase