# Does using keywords in the image URL help the image rank for those keywords in Google image search?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking, google-image-search, clean-urls

I've always been told to use URL Rewriting on my sites because it was better for SEO. (`http://example.com/articles?id=255` => `http://example.com/articles/rewriting-img-links`)

Now, I can see on [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant) that it might not been as important as it seemed before. Anyways, because it's more visual for the user, I'm going to keep my URIs like this.

However, I can't find any documentation on the impact of img url rewrited. Here two examples of what I call an img with URL rewrited, and one without:

```
<body>
    <h1>My Article</h1>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/rewriting-img-links.jpg" alt="">
    <p>
        ...
        Rewriting IMG links is the best
        ...
    </p>
</body>

<body>
    <h1>My Article</h1>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/fzaf4az8f4z98f4a.jpg" alt="">
    <p>
        ...
        Rewriting IMG links is just a waste of time
        ...
    </p>
</body>
```

Now, I want my image to be indexed by Google Images and that people can find it when they type "rewriting img links".

Does rewriting the img link have an impact in Google Image or is google Image juste basing itself on the content of the page where the image is based? (Or image recognition or whatever except link)