# what's wrong with repeating a keyword domain in slug?

Tags: seo, google-search, blogger

my intention is not to start  a discussion on whether it is correct to use the domain of keywords versus the domain of the brand, I need to know tips for use with a keyword domain

e.g.: 
for keywords: HTML templates bootstrap \ simple Html templates

domain: example.com

possible combinations:

- example.com/boostraps
- example.com/simples-templates
- example.com/bootstrap-templates
- example.com/blog/simples-template

etc.

Comment: Is `htmltemplates.com` your domain, or just an example?

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO", but keywords in URLs don't matter that much to Google right now.  See [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant)